# Script to monitor database growth on daily basis

Tags: sql-server-2016, monitoring, database-size

I am fairly new to databases, I have got a specific requirement to script a Job/Stored Procedure to monitor the database growth. We are currently using MS SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition with Always-ON HA.
I have setup mail server on the database. It would be even more efficient to link the output of the job to the mail.

Comment: the question is not very clear. you want to know how to send the result of a job to an email, is it?

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli To precise that is send part of the question. Initially need to figure out a way to get the size of the DBs and get the result of the job via email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a stored procedure called `DatabaseSpaceUsage`:

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools

When you execute it `exec DatabaseSpaceUsage` without any parameters, it will show space usage details inside a given database

[image: DatabaseSpaceUsage]

This procedure can also be called with parameter @command = 'log'

When called with `@command = 'log'` parameter, this SP will log result to logging table `DatabaseGrowthLogger` at database `ServerLogsDB` (DB and table need to be created)

Here is the script for creating the logging table:

```
USE [ServerLogsDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DatabaseGrowthLogger]    Script Date: 5/12/2020 12:11:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseGrowthLogger](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Server_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Database_Name] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Date_Full] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Day_Of_Week] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Log_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Log_Hour] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Table_Count] [int] NULL,
    [Total_Rows] [bigint] NULL,
    [Database_Data_MB] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,
    [Database_Index_MB] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,
    [Database_Unused_MB] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,
    [Database_Allocated_MB] [int] NULL,
    [Database_File_Size_MB] [int] NULL,
    [Percent_Used] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [Hours_Diff] [smallint] NULL,
    [Database_Allocated_Delta] [int] NULL,
    [Percent_Used_Delta] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Database_Name] ASC,
    [Date_Full] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseGrowthLogger] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Hours_Diff]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseGrowthLogger] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Database_Allocated_Delta]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseGrowthLogger] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Percent_Used_Delta]
GO
```

After you create `ServerLogsDB..DatabaseGrowthLogger` database and table, and deploy (create) stored procedure `DatabaseSpaceUsage` to any database (user or system), you need to schedule a job that will run once a day, for example at 23:58 UTC, and run below T-SQL:

```
exec DatabaseSpaceUsage @Command = 'log', @DatabaseName = 'Database1'
exec DatabaseSpaceUsage @Command = 'log', @DatabaseName = 'Database2'
...
-- in @DatabaseName parameter, supply database names of databases for which you want to monitor growth
```

This will log daily growth of your databases, and when you check `ServerLogsDB..DatabaseGrowthLogger` table, it will look similar to below:

[image: Data and Index Growth Rate]

Looking at logging table, you will have an idea how much data inside your database has grown over time

Finally, you can add a step to the job, that will read last row from `ServerLogsDB..DatabaseGrowthLogger` and send it by email using `sp_send_dbmail` procedure

Comment: I can't find the file on the given link. was it renamed? Thanks

Comment: @bokswager yes, procedure `SpaceUsedRating` has been updated and renamed to `DatabaseSpaceUsage`, plus logging functionality has been disabled (commented) - was going to refactor it;  I'll try to make necessary changes this week and update this answer post as well

Comment: @bokswager updated stored procedure and above answer post, check it out and let me know if everything works